# method parameter with multiple interface restrictions

Tags: c#, generics, parameters, interface

In C# it's possible to defined a method parameter with two interface restrictions. This with bounds. For example.

```
interface IA
{
  int A {get;}
}
interface IB
{
  int B {get;}
}
void Foo<T>(T param1) where T: IA, IB    {}
```

So two interfaces, and the first parameter (`param1`) of the method `Foo` should implement both interfaces.

But is this really useful? AFAIK it's not possible to cast an object to multiple interfaces in C#? Of course a class can implement two interfaces.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make a parameter implement two interfaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772053/is-it-possible-to-make-a-parameter-implement-two-interfaces)

Comment: @RobertMacLean not an duplicate. This is the other way around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very useful if the templatized class requires functionality from multiple interfaces.  For instance maybe you require classes to be comparable to one another, [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey2t2ys5.aspx), and you also want to make sure the user of your template class remembers to override `ToString()` so the data can be displayed, [IFormattable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk5yxz0f.aspx).

That is somewhat of a contrived answer but being able to specify precise interfaces multiple times allow you to keep functionality in its interface without getting one cluttered.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you have genericized logic which requires functionality from multiple types simultaneously. For example, I once had to perform the same logic on the `Button`, `LinkButton`, and `ImageButton` controls from ASP.NET. They each separately derive from `WebControl` and implement the `IButtonControl` interface; there is no base class which unites them.

I needed to wire a handler to the `Click` event, exposed by `IButtonControl`, and set a client click handler through the `Attributes` collection, which is exposed by `WebControl`. To enable a method which does both, my only choice was multiple type constraints:

```
private T CreateButton<T>() where T : WebControl, IButtonControl, new()
{
    var button = new T();

    button.Click += ...;

    button.Attributes["onClick"] = ...;

    return button;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly assign it to one at a time:

```
IA asIA = param1;
IB asIB = param1;
```

Further, you can use it as either, even without those lines (assume these take a IA or IB parameter, respectively)

```
IAFunc(param1);
IBFunc(param1);
```

Comment: @Keith, I don't follow.  First of all, `Foo` is a method not a type, so "is a Foo" doesn't make sense.  Second of all, neither `IAFunc` nor `IBFunc` has to know that param1 is also a IB or IA (respectively).  They can just treat it as a regular instance of the type in their name.

Comment: Forget it. I see what you're trying to say you can do is within the context of Foo as a method.