# Specifying multiple interfaces for a parameter

Tags: c#, interface, composition

I have an object that implements two interfaces... The interfaces are:

```
public interface IObject
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Class { get; }
    IEnumerable<IObjectProperty> Properties { get; }
}
public interface ITreeNode<T>
{
    T Parent { get; }
    IEnumerable<T> Children { get; }
}
```

such that

```
public class ObjectNode : IObject, ITreeNode<IObject>
{
    public string Class { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<IObjectProperty> Properties { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IObject> Children { get; private set; }
    public IObject Parent { get; private set; }
}
```

Now i have a function which needs one of its parameters to implement both of these interfaces. How would i go about specifying that in C#?

An example would be

```
public TypedObject(ITreeNode<IObject> baseObject, IEnumerable<IType> types, ITreeNode<IObject>, IObject parent)
{
    //Construct here
}
```

Or is the problem that my design is wrong and i should be implementing both those interfaces on one interface somehow

Comment: "Now i have a function which needs one of its parameters to implement both of these interfaces." Functions or parameters don't implement interfaces, classes implement interfaces. What do you mean?

Comment: see edits. I know that only classes can implement interfaces

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make a parameter implement two interfaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772053/is-it-possible-to-make-a-parameter-implement-two-interfaces)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
public void Foo<T>(T myParam)
    where T : IObject, ITreeNode<IObject>
{
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer. I realised that i left some crucial piece of information out. The function i am refering to is the constructor for another class (The scenario is a Node building another node) Can generics be used in a constructor

Comment: Since this answer is valid for my question i will accept it, but the constructor thing is causing me a headache :)

Comment: In that case I think you'd have to make the class generic. It doesn't look like you can have a generic constructor on a non-generic class.

Comment: Good solution for methods. Unfortunately it's difficult to apply this solution to properties without making the all class generic.

Comment: @AgostinoX Indeed. The value of a property has to have a single type. You could pick one interface as the property type, and have the setter verify that the value implements the other interface too, but there's no way for the getter to say that it will always return a value implementing both interfaces. (That's the kind of thing Code Contracts were good for.)

Comment: For Moq purposes I still had to create a shared interface in my test class which I could mock that inherited both interfaces, but this solution is great for the production code and kept that pure and clean.

Comment: Here is a workaround for generic constructor [Generic Type in constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700966/generic-type-in-constructor). Not especially good, but better, than nothing. ;)

Answer (score 14):

In C#, interfaces can themselves inherit from one or more other interfaces. So one solution would be to define an interface, say `IObjectTreeNode<T>` that derives from both `IObject` and `ITreeNode<T>`.

Comment: -1: This would change the requirement. This method does not require the parameter to implement IObject and ITreeNode<T>, it would require the parameter to implement IObjectTreeNode<T>. So objects implementing both interfaces but not the combined are not allowed, while they should.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably easiest to define an interface that implements both IObject and ITreeNode.

```
public interface IObjectNode<T> : IObject, ITreeNode<T>
{
}
```

Another option, in case you don't expect the above interface would be used often, is to make the method/function in question generic.

```
public void Foo<T>(T objectNode) where T : IObject, ITreeNode<IObject>
```

Comment: -1; this merely repeats earlier answers and doesn't acknowledge [the drawback pointed out by Stijn in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073440/specifying-multiple-interfaces-for-a-parameter#comment69322597_4073481) about the first approach.

Answer (score -5):

```
public  void MethodName<TParam1, TParam2>(TParam1 param1, TParam2 param2) 
    where TParam1 : IObject
    where TParam2 : ITreeNode<IObject>
```

Comment: You've defined one parameter that implements `IObject` and another that implements `ITreeNode<IObject>`, but I think the asker needs a single parameter that implements both.